# Why my action listener isn't called

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces dialog where I am asking for user details.  I simplified it to have only one input text like the one below.

```
<p:dialog>
        <h:form  prependId="false">
            <p:growl showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true"  life="4000"/>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="First Name" />
                <p:inputTextarea  required="true" requiredMessage="First Name is required!" />
                <p:commandButton value="Add" actionListener="#{myBean.addUser}"/>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

I notice that when I don't input my first name, my action listener isn't called which I think is normal since `required="true"` validation already happened.

Is there a way to configure this, where my action listener will still be called?
or do I have to remove the `required="true"` checking and put all the validation in my action listener method?

Comment: so basically you are asking Is that possible to "configure" `required="true"` to behave like `required="false"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not put validation logic into an action method.

If you need to do more validation than the required-check, use a custom validator for this. The action method should simply add the user and should rely on the jsf validation phase.

See [this link on the different validation options](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-validator-in-jsf-2-0/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call your `actionListener` method regardless to the value of `<p:inputTextarea/>` just remove the `required="true"` and do the validation in your action method:

```
   public void addUser() {

       if(StringUtils.isBlank(user.firstName)) {
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error! ",
                "First Name is required!"));
           return;
       }
   }
```

*isBlank from import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;*

Unrelated:

In my opinion, this approach seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: The action method is a bad place for validation. At this stage, the model values are already updated and resetting them to their previous/initial value is a hassle (that could be avoided if you validate in the JSF process validation phase).

Comment: you are absolutely right, I never place validations in my action method. You comment perfectly covert the term "bad idea" in my answer, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: never thought about good practice...I will start reading on validation part.  Right now, all of my validation is done in the action listener method.  Thanks for the lead...